# I need suggestions to fix my python code's bug that involves trying to find watt_hours and amp_hours?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, debugging

I am very new to programming in python and in general. I am currently trying to practice writing a program for an upcoming project with solar power. I need to be able to enter volts, watts, and amps to calculate amp-hours and watt-hours while having one unknown variable. I would like some suggestions to make my code better and to fix the bugs I have.

I use a -1 in my code when it asks for input for amps, volts, and watts as a way to show an unknown variable. When I know watts and volts and I don't know amps the program runs fine to calculate watt_hours and amp_hours. However, when I enter a -1 for an unknown variable for watts or volts my amp_hours and watt_hours become negative, which is not a real value. I could use suggestions on making this simple program run smoother without any bugs. Any suggestions help! I got stuck on what to do next, but I would like to be able to see how more experienced programmers would approach this slight issue.

FYI: This program is used for a solar build for a campervan:

```
**My code:**

#defining watts amps volts, amps-hours, and watt-hours.
def watts_calc(x, y):
    return amps * volts

def amps_calc(x, y):
    return watts/volts

def volts_calc(x, y):
    return watts / amps

def amp_hour(x, y):
    return amps * hours

def watt_hour(x, y):
    return watts * hours

#How many appliances are used in the Van
appliance_number = int(input("How many appliances are you trying to use? "))

#Setting up conditional arguments for while loop
condition = 1 

while condition <= appliance_number:

#Defining varibles
    amps = float(input("How many Amps does the device use: "))
    volts = float(input("How many Volts does the device use: "))
    watts = float(input("How many Watts is used: "))
    hours = float(input("How many hours of use? "))
    print("\n")

#a if/elif statement that takes input of watts, volts, amps in
    #to calculate the missing variable indicated by -1

    if amps == -1:
        print("Amps are: " + str(amps_calc(watts, volts)) + "A")
    elif volts == -1:
        print("Volts are: " + str(volts_calc(watts, amps)) + "v")
    elif watts == -1:
        print("Watts are: " + str(watts_calc(amps, hours)) + "W")
    
    else:
        print("Invalid Input")
    
    print("Watt-hours for appliance " + str(condition) + ": " + str(watt_hour(watts, hours)))
    print("Amp-hours for appliance " + str(condition) + ": " + str(amps_calc(watts, volts) * hours) + "\n")
    condition += 1
```

Comment: Maye be better suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, I don't know what I'm doing. ha!

Comment: Actually I can see what the problem is, so I'll answer it anyway.

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that where you have a `-1` for an unknown value, you are just printing out what the value should be, but you are not actually updating it for the subsequent calculations.  Save the result in the relevant variable, and it should be fine.

```
    if amps == -1:
        amps = amps_calc(watts, volts)
        print("Amps are: " + str(amps) + "A")
    elif volts == -1:
        volts = volts_calc(watts, amps)
        print("Volts are: " + str(volts) + "v")
    elif watts == -1:
        watts = watts_calc(amps, hours)
        print("Watts are: " + str(watts) + "W")
```

Someone else's answer spotted an additional problem, which while not the main source of your issue, also needs correcting. That answer has for some reason since been deleted, so I'll mention it here myself. In your functions you are ignoring the `x` and `y` parameters in the function and are instead using variables from the outer scope.  Whilst you happen to get away with that in this case, it clearly needs fixing also.  For example,

```
def watts_calc(x, y):
    return amps * volts
```

should be:

```
def watts_calc(amps, volts):
    return amps * volts
```

Then `amps` and `volts` will be function parameters rather than variables used from the outer scope. (You could also use `x` and `y` but the meanings are then less clear.)

Comment: That was it thanks!!! I thought I had to rewrite everything. Just beginning so hey. Also, thank you for directing me to the proper place to post code!

Comment: @GaryThomas There is another issue also though. I've updated my answer to mention it also.

Comment: @GaryThomas Also I think on balance your question was fine here. The way you had written it, it sounded at first like you were wanting general suggestions about improving your code, but in fact it came down to finding a specific bug.

Comment: Well, I intended it to be like that. Yes, I had the bug issue, but I have no clue how to properly or efficiently formulate what I was trying to get at in this program. I know it works especially after your suggestion, but I am not sure at all if this is a good way to actually acomplish the task at hand. I will keep that in mind for future questions though!

Answer (score 0):

first of all you might want to store those numbers in variables in the methods, you could instead of having them input a number, have them put in a char for each metric they want to use, or one char for the metric they want to find, then just have list of those chars and use for loops, or you could experiment with lamdba instead of using standars syntax for thos functions

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the only way you would have a negative value is if you have multiple inputs that are negative. However, it seems like you wish to only allow one variable to be unknown. Let me know if this isn't the case.

There are a few ways to approach this. One way is to reformat your code to ask for which calculation the user wishes to do and then prompt for values accordingly.

Another would be to use assert within your functions or to check whether one of the values is negative with an if statement.
You may also wish to combine both of these.

Let me know if you have any follow-up questions.

Comment: Yeah, I only want to have one unknown variable due to the application of what I am doing. Usually, I will always know two variables, typically watts and volts. I know these values because they are the most common to find on the back of the appliance or the system. I am using is a 12-volt system, so most things that will be connected will be 12v. I just wanted to allow extra room if watts or volts are not as easily accessible. Thank you for the help and suggestions! I am just kind of taking in all the replies of how I am able to do things differently in my code. Its amazing.